# How to stick labels to the right scale?

Tags: pine-script

Instead of a long explanation, please have a look at the screenshot.

Both the upper line and its label are the result of a pine script. At the moment, the label's placement along the X-axis is arbitrarily defined by an offset value. What I'd like though is for the label to constantly stick to the right scale no matter how I scroll the chart horizontally.

In other words and as per the screenshot below, I'd like this label to behave exactly as the text added to the Horizontal Ray (Text alignement has been set to "Top Right" in this example).

IS there a workaround to achieve such a result as the official doc on label doesn't show any dedicated solution?

Thanks for your help.

[Screenshot of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz2Jw.png)

The code as of now is:

```
label.new(x=myOffset, y=23000, text='PINESCRIPT RESULT', xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=#2962ff, style=label.style_label_center, textcolor=color.white, size=size.normal)
```

The position of the label along the X-axis is set based on "offset" (user configurable).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

There is `chart.right_visible_bar_time` built-in variable but it will point to the rightmost bar on your chart and not the right edge of your chart. It might come handy when looking at historical data.

```
label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, close, "Close: " + str.tostring(close), xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, that's not exactly what I'm looking for as you have rightly pointed.
Actually, I was more expecting a workaround sort of solution because as per the manual about hline, line and labels, there's nothing dedicated to achieve this result.